# Como obter um field específico de uma classe mesmo sendo herdado

Tags: java, reflexão

Eu estou enfrentando problemas ao tentar obter um field de uma classe, eu estou, sempre, recebendo o erro `NoSuchFieldException`. O que se sabe é que essa field é herdada e privada de uma outra classe, porém a classe pai pode ser uma filha de outra, e assim por diante.

O que eu preciso é encontrar esse field mesmo que ela seja filha de outra, e assim por diante.

Obs:

1. Qualquer dúvida não hesite em tirar.
2. Qualquer exemplo de código seria muito útil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente algo assim:

```
public static Field acharField(Class<?> onde, String nome) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    if (onde == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    if (nome == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    NoSuchFieldException excecao = null;
    for (Class<?> c = onde; c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
        try {
            return c.getDeclaredField(nome);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            if (excecao == null) excecao = e;
        }
    }
    throw excecao;
}
```

O método [`getDeclaredField(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)) procura pelo `Field` na classe em questão, mesmo se ele for privado. No entanto, esse método não procura nas superclasses, e é por isso que esse código usa uma iteração para ir tentando nas superclasses até achar.

Ele vai procurar o `Field` na classe e se não encontrar, vai tentando as superclasses até chegar em `Object`. Se de fato não encontrar em lugar nenhum, lança o primeiro `NoSuchFieldException` obtido. Se qualquer parâmetro for `null`, lança `NullPointerException`.

[**Veja no ideone um teste desse método funcionando.**](https://ideone.com/v1olcT)